# Boundedness of $\exp\Big(\alpha\,{\bf Re}(z\overline{w}) - \beta |z|² - \gamma |w|²\Big)$.

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

> Let $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ be positive constants. I am interested in finding conditions on these such that the function
>   \begin{align*}
> f: \mathbb{C}^2 &\to \mathbb{C}\\
> f(z,w)&= \exp\Big(\alpha\,{\bf Re}(z\overline{w}) - \beta |z|² - \gamma |w|²\Big)
> \end{align*}
>   is bounded.

I found that $4\beta \gamma \geq \alpha^2$ is sufficient for the boundedness. But is this also necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write

$$f(z,w) = \exp \bigl((\alpha - 2\sqrt{\beta\gamma})\operatorname{Re} (z\overline{w}) - \bigl\lvert \sqrt{\beta} z - \sqrt{\gamma}w\bigr\rvert^2\bigr).$$

Therefore

$$f(z,\sqrt{\beta/\gamma}z) = \exp\bigl((\alpha - 2\sqrt{\beta\gamma})\sqrt{\beta/\gamma}\lvert z\rvert^2\bigr),$$

and we see that

$$\alpha \leqslant 2\sqrt{\beta\gamma}$$

is necessary for the boundedness of $f$.